# What are the releases cycles for NEAR protocol networks?

Tags: nearprotocol

There are devnet, betanet, testnet networks in NEAR protocol at the moment. When do they get released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently devnet gets released daily, betanet weekly and testnet monthly. It might be subject to change in the future.

Comment: Are there fixed dates of the week / month?

Comment: devnet gets released on 0:00 UTC every day and betanet gets released on 0:00 UTC every Wednesday. For testnet we have not yet finalized when it gets released.